# Why do my p-values change after rescaling variables? Mixed Models

Tags: r, scaling, lme4, mixed-models, p-value

I have this code `m2 <- lmer(SE ~ b95rel*MF*TASK*ROI*side*Run + (1|IDcheck),f)` where `SE`, `b95rel` and `MF` are continuous variables, `TASK`, `ROI`, `side` and `Run` are categorical variables.

I get the warning message:

> Warning messages:
> 1: Some predictor variables are on very different scales: consider rescaling

Here the first rows of the result:
[image]

When I rescale `b95rel`, p-values change (e.g. the main effect `TASK` becomes significant):

[image]

When I also rescale `MF`, p-values change again:

[image]

I use the `scale()` function in R.

Online I always read that p-values shouldn't change when scaling, so I'm confused what it means if mine change...

This is the scaled MF variable:

[image]

This is the unscaled `MF` variable: dots do not change distance to each other. The same I see for the other variables after and before scaling. Only the y-axis values change. So the change in p values cannot come from here...

[image]

I currently don't manage to copy the `dput()` outome here as my data file is too big with its numerous repeated variables...I will see if I find a solution and put it into a comment...

Here the sessionInfo:

```r
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.2.2 (2022-10-31 ucrt)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19044)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_Canada.utf8  LC_CTYPE=English_Canada.utf8    LC_MONETARY=English_Canada.utf8
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                    LC_TIME=English_Canada.utf8    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] rstatix_0.7.2   ggpubr_0.6.0    lubridate_1.9.2 forcats_1.0.0   stringr_1.5.0   dplyr_1.1.1    
 [7] purrr_1.0.1     readr_2.1.4     tidyr_1.3.0     tibble_3.2.1    ggplot2_3.4.2   tidyverse_2.0.0
[13] sjmisc_2.8.9    sjPlot_2.8.14   MuMIn_1.47.5    lmerTest_3.1-3  lme4_1.1-32     Matrix_1.5-4   
[19] sjstats_0.18.2  emmeans_1.8.5  

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] splines_4.2.2       carData_3.0-5       modelr_0.1.11       datawizard_0.7.1    stats4_4.2.2       
 [6] bayestestR_0.13.1   numDeriv_2016.8-1.1 pillar_1.9.0        backports_1.4.1     lattice_0.20-45    
[11] glue_1.6.2          RColorBrewer_1.1-3  ggsignif_0.6.4      minqa_1.2.5         colorspace_2.1-0   
[16] sandwich_3.0-2      pkgconfig_2.0.3     broom_1.0.4         haven_2.5.2         xtable_1.8-4       
[21] mvtnorm_1.1-3       scales_1.2.1        tzdb_0.3.0          timechange_0.2.0    farver_2.1.1       
[26] generics_0.1.3      car_3.1-2           sjlabelled_1.2.0    TH.data_1.1-1       withr_2.5.0        
[31] cli_3.4.1           effectsize_0.8.3    survival_3.4-0      magrittr_2.0.3      estimability_1.4.1 
[36] fansi_1.0.4         nlme_3.1-160        MASS_7.3-60         tools_4.2.2         hms_1.1.3          
[41] lifecycle_1.0.3     multcomp_1.4-23     munsell_0.5.0       ggeffects_1.2.2     compiler_4.2.2     
[46] rlang_1.1.0         grid_4.2.2          nloptr_2.0.3        parameters_0.20.3   rstudioapi_0.14    
[51] labeling_0.4.2      boot_1.3-28         gtable_0.3.3        codetools_0.2-18    abind_1.4-5        
[56] R6_2.5.1            zoo_1.8-11          knitr_1.42          performance_0.10.3  utf8_1.2.3         
[61] insight_0.19.1      stringi_1.7.12      Rcpp_1.0.10         vctrs_0.6.1         tidyselect_1.2.0   
[66] xfun_0.38           coda_0.19-4
```

Comment: Would be the case of z-transform the continuous variable?!

Comment: Online I found that to transform it into a z-score, your can use the scale() function and put `scale = TRUE`, `center = TRUE`. The results still does not give the same p-values as before.
`df <- f%>% group_by(ROI, side, Run, TASK) %>% 
  mutate(MFs = scale(MF,scale = T, center = T),
         SEs = scale(SE,scale = T, center = T),
         b95rels = scale(b95rel,scale = T, center = T))`

Comment: Can you please edit your question to include the `anova()` results as text (e.g., cut-and-paste into a code block delimited with ```) rather than images?

Answer (score 3):

**tl;dr** if you `scale(..., center = FALSE)` the p-values should stay constant. *However*, you should **always be cautious about interpreting the significance of main effects in the presence of interactions**, precisely because they depend on the centering of the other effects in the interaction (Venables 1988). Venables says, effectively, "never interpret main effects in the presence of interactions"; my revision of that is "unless you know and can explain exactly why it could be problematic, and thus understand what you're actually testing".

Your problem is two-fold: (1) by default, `scale()` **centers** as well as scaling variables; (2) centering changes the meaning, and p-values, of *main effects* when they are involved in higher-order effects that are also contained in the model.

The examples below show effects based on the coefficient tables from `summary()` rather than using `anova()`, but the point is the same.

I'll give an example with `lm()` (since this isn't specific to mixed models):

```r
m1 <- lm(mpg ~ hp*disp, mtcars)
## utility function
p <- function(m) print(coef(summary(m))[,"Pr(>|t|)"], digits = 3)
p(m1)
## (Intercept)          hp        disp     hp:disp 
##   7.18e-14    4.73e-04    2.11e-05    2.41e-03
```

Scale and center: the interaction p-value stays the same, but the other effects change (because we are now evaluating effects at the *mean* of the other variable, rather than when the other variable is 0)

```r
msc <- transform(mtcars, hp = scale(hp), disp = scale(disp))
p(update(m1, data = msc))
## (Intercept)          hp        disp     hp:disp 
##   1.64e-20    1.30e-02    4.36e-05    2.41e-03
```

Scale but don't center: p-values the same as the original model.

```r
msc <- transform(mtcars, hp = scale(hp, center = FALSE), disp = scale(disp, center= FALSE))
p(update(m1, data = msc))
## (Intercept)          hp        disp     hp:disp 
##   7.18e-14    4.73e-04    2.11e-05    2.41e-03
```

PS if you want to interpret 'type 3' anova, you should probably also be using sum-to-zero contrasts (`options(contrasts = c("contr.sum", "contr.poly"))`)

---

Venables, W. N. 1998. “Exegeses on Linear Models.” 1998 International S-PLUS User Conference. Washington, DC. http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/pub/MASS3/Exegeses.pdf.

Comment: Thank you so much for your amazing comment. For some reason, I still get different results depending on which variables I scale. Here an example:
`m2 <- lmer(SEs ~ b95rels*MFs*TASK*ROI*side*Run + (1|IDcheck),df)
> drop1(m2, test="F")
Single term deletions using Satterthwaite's method:

Model:
SEs ~ b95rels * MFs * TASK * ROI * side * Run + (1 | IDcheck)
                                   Sum Sq      Mean Sq NumDF DenDF F value Pr(>F)
b95rels:MFs:TASK:ROI:side:Run 0.000012799 0.0000042662     3 671.6  0.0914 0.964`

Comment: `> m2 <- lmer(SE ~ b95rel*MF*TASK*ROI*side*Run + (1|IDcheck),f)
> drop1(m2, test="F")
Single term deletions using Satterthwaite's method:

Model:
SE ~ b95rel * MF * TASK * ROI * side * Run + (1 | IDcheck)
                                 Sum Sq      Mean Sq NumDF  DenDF F value Pr(>F)
b95rel:MF:TASK:ROI:side:Run 0.000016285 0.0000054283     3 671.58  0.1204 0.9481`

Comment: `m2 <- lmer(SE ~ b95rels*MF*TASK*ROI*side*Run + (1|IDcheck),df)
> drop1(m2, test="F")
Single term deletions using Satterthwaite's method:

Model:
SE ~ b95rels * MF * TASK * ROI * side * Run + (1 | IDcheck)
                                   Sum Sq      Mean Sq NumDF  DenDF F value Pr(>F)
b95rels:MF:TASK:ROI:side:Run 0.0000071936 0.0000023978     3 671.47  0.0532 0.9838`

Comment: The variables ending with an 's' are scaled. In the first model, all continous variables are scaled. In the second model, no variable is scaled and in the last one, only b95rel is scaled.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't think I can answer this without a reproducible example.  To be clear, (1) you're *definitely* scaling but not centering and (2) you're not getting any warning messages?

Comment: (3) it's conceivable (although I hope not) that scaling affects the Satterthwaite correction. Can you try with `drop1(m2, test="Chisq")` and see what happens?

Comment: I use this for scaling: `df <- f%>% group_by(ROI, side, Run, TASK) %>% 
  mutate(MFs = scale(MF,scale = T, center = F),
         SEs = scale(SE,scale = T, center = F),
         b95rels = scale(b95rel,scale = T, center = F))`

Comment: With Chisq instead of F I still get different p values... I will try again with the `dput()` function. Is there another way to share the datafile?

Comment: You can post it somewhere publicly accessible and include a link (having the question be self-contained is ideal, but often not practical for reasonable size data sets)

Comment: You should **not** group before scaling!  Unlike scaling the entire variable, scaling by group **will** change the data in a way that will affect all of the answers.

Comment: ok, here you can find the datafile and the code: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1sZbW_yHzjtBTs64HufLWZHzMHb9m73kQ?usp=sharing

Comment: The problem remains when I scale like this:
`f$MFs <- scale(f$MF)
f$b95rels <- scale(f$b95rel)
f$mRTs <- scale(f$mRT)
f$SEs <- scale(f$SE)`

Comment: But that scaling is not including `center = FALSE` ...